# How to iterate over the keys and values with ng-repeat in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my controller, I have data like:
`$scope.object = data`

Now this data is the dictionary with keys and values from `json`.

I can access the attribute with `object.name` in the template. Is there any way that I can iterate over the keys as well and display them in table like

`<tr><td> {{key}} </td> <td> data.key </td>`

The data is like this

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "project": "wewe2012",
    "date": "2013-02-26",
    "description": "ewew",
    "eet_no": "ewew",
}
```

Answer (score 1453, accepted):

How about:

```html
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This method is listed in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: its not working , i tried that and its showing empty. i ahve the json data in the data object. i can see the number of rows as the items but they are empty

Comment: It should work: http://plnkr.co/edit/7AQF6k7hf2aZbWFmhVoX?p=preview. Can you modify that until it stops working?

Comment: Its working with `<li>` but not working with `<tr>`. can you check why

Comment: I can't check why your code doesn't work if you don't give me your code. :-) But here is the same thing, modified for `<tr>`: http://plnkr.co/edit/7AQF6k7hf2aZbWFmhVoX?p=preview

Comment: thanks , thats working now, i think i didn't had proper table markupt with tbody , thats why it wasn't working

Comment: It'll work without that too: http://plnkr.co/edit/7AQF6k7hf2aZbWFmhVoX?p=preview. It was probably just a typo somewhere. Glad I could help!

Comment: Yep, I had an extra `tr` in there. I removed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: It works like a charm. The only catch is that it will be alphabetized by the keys so the naming matters if the item order is relevant to the display.

Comment: @IsabelHM For many reasons, a lot of us recommend against iterating over objects in an `ngRepeat`. In fact, I once heard a core team member regret ever implementing the ability to do so! It's usually better to transform the object in the controller to an array; this makes the intent clearer and decreases the risk for strange/unpredictable behavior in certain cases. And you can sort in the usual way. :-)

Comment: As IsabelHM said, the output is ordered alphabetically by the name. Is there a way to force it not to do so?

Comment: @miliu As far as I am aware, there is no built-in way to do that, no.

Comment: Is there any way to pass the key and value to an `ng-include` or to a directive?

Comment: @lmray I'm not sure what you mean; isn't that what's happening above?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Yes, using `ngRepeat` to iterate over an object is very "weird", yet it does have its uses. I have found it to be quite useful... once.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller - As of angular 1.4, ng-repeat over an object no longer plays nicely with orderBy... here's your plunk slightly modified: http://plnkr.co/edit/gi2DQaSIuWn9j3loGG7Q?p=preview.

Comment: @sethflowers As I mentioned in a previous comment, I don't recommend iterating over keys in objects. It would be better to convert it to an array in your controller. Assuming there isn't idiomatic way to do this based on your business model, ES6 makes it very easy: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).map(k => ({key:k, value:data[k]));`.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Can you explain your reasoning as to why it's bad to iterate over keys in objects and to use arrays instead? What if you're dealing with large data? I feel like you wouldn't want to have to sacrifice performance by having to search the array for the key every time you add an item to the map. I guess you could get around the performance loss by maintaining a map of key => arrayIndex, but it's adding another layer of complexity and an extra step in retrieval.

Comment: @ChrisManning I wouldn't say it's "bad", but I don't usually recommend it. Order can be unpredictable, there's often a challenge with inherited proprerties, and objects are not intended to be iterable (so your model probably doesn't reflect your business). But there are always exceptions.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller interesting that you mentioned that because I was ran into one such problem you mentioned after I typed that. Essentially I had to group certain entities based on a group UUID, and then I realized they had a property by which I needed to order them. Guess I need to sort the list pre-map creation.  
  
Of course, I had to transform it into a 2d array anyway because I'm using angular 1.2.x  
  
Thanks for the explanation/followup. Very much appreciated

Comment: The URL should be updated to: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 140):

If you would like to edit the property value with two way binding:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <td>{{key}}<input type="text" ng-model="data[key]"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, did you find this technique in docs someplace? I searched in vain until finding your answer here.

Comment: For some reason the value is updated, and inputs cursor is reset.

Comment: @cbk isn't this the same as using `ng-model="value"`?

Comment: @MikeHarrison `ng-repeat` is essentially iterating over the object and returning key-value pairs.  Think of it like `for(var value in arrayOfValues) { ... }`.  If you re-assign the variable `value` inside your loop, you are not changing what is inside of `arrayOfValues`, you are just re-pointing `value` to a new object.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think there's a builtin function in angular for doing this, but you can do this by creating a separate scope property containing all the header names, and you can fill this property automatically like this:

```
var data = {
  foo: 'a',
  bar: 'b'
};

$scope.objectHeaders = [];

for ( property in data ) {
  $scope.objectHeaders.push(property); 
}

// Output: [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
```

Comment: Your answer works fine if one needs to loop through the data inside an angular controller (OP asked for a view loop).

Answer (score 5):

we can follow below procedure to avoid display of key-values in alphabetical order.

**Javascript**

```
$scope.data = {
   "id": 2,
   "project": "wewe2012",
   "date": "2013-02-26",
   "description": "ewew",
   "eet_no": "ewew",
};
var array = [];
for(var key in $scope.data){
    var test = {};
    test[key]=$scope.data[key];
    array.push(test);
}
$scope.data = array;
```

**HTML**

```
<p ng-repeat="obj in data">
   <font ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
      {{key}} : {{value}}
   </font>
</p>
```

Comment: Duplicate in keyword not aloowed

Answer (score 4):

A *todo list* example which loops over object by `ng-repeat`:

```js
var app = angular.module('toDolistApp', []);
app.controller('toDoListCntrl', function() {
  var self = this;
  self.toDoListItems = {};// []; //dont use square brackets if keys are string rather than numbers.
  self.doListCounter = 0;

  self.addToDoList = function() {         
    var newToDoItem = {};
    newToDoItem.title     = self.toDoEntry;
    newToDoItem.completed = false;     

    var keyIs = "key_" + self.doListCounter++;       

    self.toDoListItems[keyIs] = newToDoItem;     
    self.toDoEntry = ""; //after adding the item make the input box blank.
  };
});

app.filter('propsCounter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return Object.keys(input).length;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="toDolistApp">    
  <div ng-controller="toDoListCntrl as toDoListCntrlAs">
    Total Items: {{toDoListCntrlAs.toDoListItems | propsCounter}}<br />
    Enter todo Item:  <input type="text" ng-model="toDoListCntrlAs.toDoEntry"/>
    <span>{{toDoListCntrlAs.toDoEntry}}</span>
    <button ng-click="toDoListCntrlAs.addToDoList()">Add Item</button> <br/>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, prop) in toDoListCntrlAs.toDoListItems"> 
      <span>{{$index+1}} : {{key}}   : Title = {{ prop.title}} : Status = {{ prop.completed}} </span>
    </div>     
  </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: The comment about not using square brackets was really helpful. That change fixed my code. Thanks.

Comment: Me too. Can someone explain why using curly brackets fixed my code?

Answer (score 1):

**Complete example here:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html ng-app="dashboard">
<head>
<title>AngularJS</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="./bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <table border='1'>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in collValues">
            <td ng-if="!hasChildren(val)">{{key}}</td>  
            <td ng-if="val === 'string'">
                <input type="text" name="{{key}}"></input>
            </td>
            <td ng-if="val === 'number'">
                <input type="number" name="{{key}}"></input>
            </td>
            <td ng-if="hasChildren(val)" td colspan='2'>
                <table border='1' ng-repeat="arrVal in val">
                    <tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in arrVal">
                        <td>{{key}}</td>    
                        <td ng-if="val === 'string'">
                            <input type="text" name="{{key}}"></input>
                        </td>
                        <td ng-if="val === 'number'">
                            <input type="number" name="{{key}}"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                
            </td>

        </tr>       
    </table>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("dashboard",[]);
    app.controller("myController",function($scope){
        $scope.collValues = {
            'name':'string',
            'id':'string',
            'phone':'number',
            'depart':[
                    {
                        'depart':'string',
                        'name':'string' 
                    }
            ]   
        };

        $scope.hasChildren = function(bigL1) {
            return angular.isArray(bigL1);
} 
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Use below code it is working to display your key and value here is key start with 1:
         <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in alert_list" >
                   <td>{{key +1}}</td>
                   <td>{{value.title}}</td>
                 </tr>
Below is document link for it.
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your javascript (controller) or in your html (angular view)...

js:

```
$scope.arr = [];
for ( p in data ) {
  $scope.arr.push(p); 
}
```

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(k, v) in data">
    <td>{{k}}<input type="text" ng-model="data[k]"></td>
</tr>
```

I believe the html way is more angular , but you can also do in your controller and retrieve it in your html...

also not a bad idea to look at the Object keys, they give you the an array of the keys if you need them, more info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys