# Nested Ng-Repeat and object properties

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object which contains many objects. The objects property is a users name property contains an object who's properties are groups and the value is either true or false.

```
ReportModel.Taxonomy = {
    Authenticated Users: Object
    Test Group 1: " &#x2713; "
    Test Group 2: " &#x2713; "
    Test Group 3: " - "
    Test Group 4: " - "
    Test Group 5: " &#x2713; "
    Test Group 6: " - "
    Test Group 7: " - "
    Test Group 8: " &#x2713; "
    TestGroup: " - "
Test Users: Object
    Test Group 1: " - "
    Test Group 2: " - "
    Test Group 3: " - "
    Test Group 4: " &#x2713; "
    Test Group 5: " - "
    Test Group 6: " &#x2713; "
    Test Group 7: " - "
    Test Group 8: " - "
    TestGroup: " - "
}
```

**I've been trying to create a table using ng-repeat where each row, after the headers, provides the username (column 1) and the result for each of the groups:**

```
    <table>
        <tr class="reportHeader" >
            <th>USERS</th>
            <th ng-repeat="group in ReportModel.groups">{{group.name}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in ReportModel.taxonomy">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="user.userGroups"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I can't figure out how to use ngRepeat given the way the Taxonomy object is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do: 
[How can I iterate over the keys, value in ng-repeat in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)

for example:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, user) in ReportModel.taxonomy">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="(key, group) in user"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes. Wow, that's exactly it. Thank you.