# Angularjs ng-repeat: iterate over a special object fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object:

```
var options = {
    NAME_1 : "Name 1",
    TEXT_1 : "Description goes here",
    NAME_2 : "Name 2",
    TEXT_2 : "Description2 goes here",
};
```

Is it possible to iterate over the fields of the object inside the ng-repeat?
E.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in options">
    <span class="title">{{item.name}}</span>
    <span class="text">{{item.text}}</span>
</div>
```

I will greatly appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited my answer with a complete solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i iterate over the keys , value in ng-repeat in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not going to work as you imagine, perhaps your object can look like this,

```
var options = [
{
name : "Name 1",
text : "Description goes here"
},
{
name : "Name 2",
text : "Description2 goes here"
}
];
```

now you can iterate just as you want it.

Or, you can I guess iterate over all your values in the object but you need to keep in mind that these values are not really related to each other, besides just being in the same object.

This is the solution with ng-if and iterate over the object.  But as I mentioned, javascript iterates over objects not in order so your best bet to reorder your properties in an array and then iterate again.  This below iterate as NAME_1, NAME_2, TEXT_1, TEXT_2

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var options = {
    NAME_1 : "Name 1",
    TEXT_1 : "Description goes here",
    NAME_2 : "Name 2",
    TEXT_2 : "Description2 goes here",
};
$scope.options = options;
$scope.check = function(title, key) {
   if(key.split('_')[0] === title) {
     return true;
   } 
}
});

<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in options|orderBy:k">
    <span ng-class="title" ng-if="check('NAME',k)">{{k}}</span>
    <span ng-class="text" ng-if="check('TEXT',k)">{{k}}</span>     
</div>
```

COMPLETE SOLUTION:
If you also use underscore, you can do this.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in optionsArray">
      <span ng-class="title" ng-if="check('NAME',x)">{{x[1]}}</span>
      <span ng-class="text" ng-if="check('TEXT',x)">{{x[1]}}</span>
</div>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var options = {
    NAME_1: "Name 1",
    TEXT_1: "Description goes here",
    NAME_2: "Name 2",
    TEXT_2: "Description2 goes here",
  };
  $scope.options = options;
  $scope.optionsArray = _.pairs(options);
  $scope.check = function(title, key) {
    if (key[0].split('_')[0] === title) {
      return true;
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: I cannot modify the object. This is how it is returned by a 3-d party service. I was thinking about combining ng-if and using "odd" parameter inside the cycle.

Comment: that wouldn't work because javascript iterates over object properties in not an orderly fashion.  I edited my answer though for also what you were asking.  So you can kinda work on that.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely! Use the following syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k, v) in options">
```

As you can guess, `k` is the key and `v` is the value of the key.

Comment: You can use any valid identifiers you like, of course, not just "k" and "v".