# SignaR + AngularJS Array property change is not modifying UI

Tags: angularjs, signalr, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a chat application and wanted to display availability of users on UI.
I am using SignalR and AngularJS.

But UI is not updating after I update members online property like below,

```
self.hubProxy.client.isAvailable = function (loggedinuser, isOnline) {
      $scope.$apply(function () {
        self.allMembers[loggedinuser].isOnline  = isOnline;
    });
```

I am using ng-repeat="member in allMembers" to bind with all members and using its isOnline property to apply a class.

Comment: Is your `isAvailable` function being called?

Comment: yes, isAvailable is being called, i debugged it to view that, also values are being set on the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your method gets called, and assuming that `loggedinuser` is the name of the user, then your problem might be with `ngRepeat`, because you should be enumerating by key:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in allMembers"
```

Check this: [How can I iterate over the keys, value in ng-repeat in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Comment: i tried above by having ng-repeat="(key,value) in allMembers" and by using  <div>
                        <div style="background-color:green" ng-show="{{value.isOnline}}">
                            Online
                        </div>
                        <div>{{value.memberFullName}}</div>
                    </div>  , full name is being displayed but the div with background being set as green is not displayed even the value is set.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the issue it seems ng-show does not reflect changes , when i tried using ng-class="{'isAvailable': value.isOnline, 'isOffline': !value.isOnline}" it worked..

Comment: ng-show should definitely reflect changes, glad you solved it anyway