# ng-repeat of JSON which have index on it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json like this

```
  {
    "0": {
        "Order_Id": "100000001",
        "prodct_Status": "Pending",
        "Price": "8.0000",
        "date_created": "Jun 4, 2014 7:55:42 AM",
        "Shipping_Address": "vbccv",
        "Region": "Arizona",
        "Country": "US"
    },
    "1": {
        "Order_Id": "100000002",
        "prodct_Status": "Pending",
        "Price": "38.4600",
        "date_created": "Jun 7, 2014 6:37:48 AM",
        "Shipping_Address": "vbccv",
        "Region": "Arizona",
        "Country": "US"
    },
    "2": {
        "Order_Id": "100000003",
        "prodct_Status": "Pending",
        "Price": "44.9200",
        "date_created": "Jun 10, 2014 4:52:46 AM",
        "Shipping_Address": "vbccv",
        "Region": "Arizona",
        "Country": "US"
    }
}
```

I wanna do ng repeat in this json . I have those 0 1 index there which i can not remove .

Comment: it seems you JSON is inccorect, could you check it ?

Comment: This is invalid JSON.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :message: "Unexpected token :"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: Error

Comment: You have a object of objects in your example. Maybe it should be an array of objects? It should look like this [{},{},...,{}]

Comment: casper i cant edit that json I dont have controll over that . is there any way in this json. and narek json validator validated it

Comment: This IS valid JSON. Try jsonlint.org. But @AshishNautiyal: you don't have an index of "1" but a property of `1` and `2` which makes a difference!

Comment: @NoahMatisoff The JSON is perfectly valid.

Comment: @AxelAmthor yes . But is there any way to ignore this and use it in ng-repeat or get solution

Comment: @AshishNautiyal AFAIK no, you have an Object with Objects but you need an array of Objects, see previous comments

Answer (score 3):

you can use the standard ng-repeat syntax:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
      {{item.Order_Id}}
      {{item.Region}}
    </div>
  </body>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.data = {
    "0": {
        "Order_Id": "100000001",
        "prodct_Status": "Pending",
        "Price": "8.0000",
        "date_created": "Jun 4, 2014 7:55:42 AM",
        "Shipping_Address": "vbccv",
        "Region": "Arizona",
        "Country": "US"
    },
    "1": {
        "Order_Id": "100000002",
        "prodct_Status": "Pending",
        "Price": "38.4600",
        "date_created": "Jun 7, 2014 6:37:48 AM",
        "Shipping_Address": "vbccv",
        "Region": "Arizona",
        "Country": "US"
    },
    "2": {
        "Order_Id": "100000003",
        "prodct_Status": "Pending",
        "Price": "44.9200",
        "date_created": "Jun 10, 2014 4:52:46 AM",
        "Shipping_Address": "vbccv",
        "Region": "Arizona",
        "Country": "US"
    }
   };

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/o7pQvhh2KKL7xgqhtL5L?p=preview

Comment: `(key, item) in data` if you want access to the key as well: [(plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/spGLFCD1c22Ei4XuuMP4?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

ng-repeat can iterate with objects as well:

```
<div ng-repeat="(index, order) in {'0':{'Order_Id':'1'},'1':{ 'Order_Id': '2'}}">
  <span>{{ order.Order_Id }}</span>
</div>
```

In your case string index can be ignored. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15127934/438084) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
var json = { /* your json goes here */ };

<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in json">
      {{key}} {{value.Price}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/01vry4469ggGs1O1i5tI?p=preview