# How to convert JSON format in to string for view part for AngularJS

Tags: java, json, angularjs, web-services

Iam fetching data from database in a JSON format using web services. Now i need to present the json format into normal string in the view part of my AngularJS.

This my HTML file index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./hello.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Hello">
    <div ng-repeat="greeting in greetings">
        <p>The ID is {{greeting.userId}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{greeting.userName}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

`

This is my java Script file hello.js

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/RESTJerseyExample/rest/restfultest/GetCarValues').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.greetings = data;
    });
}`
```

Comment: So you please provide an example of what you are trying to do with some code and the required result?

Comment: What about JSON.stringify()?

Comment: You should be able to process the json object in angular. What is the issue you have with the current implementation.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15127834/1700321)?

Comment: It's Displaying a blank page...

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON.stringify(object)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify