# How to properly display Key Value Pairs using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, keyvaluepair

How do I correctly display key value pairs using AngularJS?

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="item-property-list">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.item_properties">
    {{key.key}} <strong>&nbsp;{{value.value}}</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JSON data:

```
"item_properties":
          [
                        {
               "key": "Size",
               "value": "S"
            },
                        {
               "key": "Color",
               "value": "Red"
            }
         ]
```

Here is the output:

```
S Red
```

I would like to have:

```
Size: S
Color: Red
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

Just access it directly:

```
 <li ng-repeat="element in item.item_properties">
    {{element.key}} <strong>&nbsp;{{element.value}}</strong>
    </li>
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! Thank you!

Comment: or  {{value.key}} <strong>&nbsp;{{value.value}}</strong> using original (key,value) pair

Answer (score 0):

`(key, value)` is for iterrating over an object that has keys and values. `item_properties` is an array, so repeat normally. Then take the repeated object and access your "key" property on it. Note that your "key" property is not a key in the KVP sense. In `{color:'red'}` `color` is a true key.

```
<ul class="item-property-list">
    <li ng-repeat="item_property in item.item_properties">
    {{item_property.key}} <strong>&nbsp;{{item_property.value}}</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```