# How to iterate through an array of arrays in JSON using ng-repeat?

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I  am trying to iterate over a JSON object `userTypes`.
For the below code:

In the 1st ng-repeat:
 `{{user.type}}` outputs **'Parent'**(*as expected*),
 `{{user.options}}` outputs **'[{"option1":"11QWERT","option2":"22QWERT"}]'**(*as expected*).

But in the 2nd `ng-repeat`, I am not able to iterate through the `user.options` and output each of the `{{options}}`

What should be changed to get the `option1` and `option2` as the outputs in 2nd  `ng-repeat` ?

**JS snippet**

```
var userTypes = [{
    "type": 'Parent',
    "options": [{
        "option1": "11QWERT",
        "option2": "22QWERT"
    }]
}]
```

**HTML snippet**

```
<li ng-repeat="user in userTypes">
    <p>{{user.type}}</p>
    <p>{{user.options}}</p>
    <li ng-repeat="option in user.options">
        <p>
            {{option}}
        </p>
    </li>
</li>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace your child `<li>` with `<ul>` and then you can iterate `user.options` like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in userTypes">
    <p>{{user.type}}</p>
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in user.options[0]">
        <p>{{key}}: {{value}}</p>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Or if your `options` may include more then one object:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in userTypes">
    <p>{{user.type}}</p>
    <ul ng-repeat="option in user.options">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in option">{{key}}: {{value}}</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

If you don't need object keys:

```
<ul ng-repeat="option in user.options">
    <li ng-repeat="item in option">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpxwx9bt/2/)

**Extended explanation:**

In your example you have `<li>` tag inside another `<li>`:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in userTypes">
    <li ng-repeat="option in user.options">
    </li>
</li>
```

Since it is not a valid HTML browser will interprets this markup to following:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in userTypes">
</li>
<li ng-repeat="option in user.options">
</li>
```

Since `ng-repeat` creates new scope for each iteration you can't access `user` variable in second `ng-repeat` and iterator wouldn't run.

Comment: @dreamer: because it is a valid HTML, otherwise browser will close first `<li>` tag automatically and you will lose your nested iteration

Answer (score 1):

For this exact JSON input it should be like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="option in user.options">
    <p>
        {{option.option1}}
        {{option.option2}}
    </p>
</li>
```

However as you said you want non fixed number of options, update your JSON to be like this:

```
"options":["11QWERT","22QWERT"]
```

And then your code should work as you wanted it.

You can add each new element to list with simple coma before it.

Comment: the number of options in `options` is not fixed. so this cannot be used?

Comment: Your JSON input is bad then, it should be:
"options":["11QWERT","22QWERT"] ill update answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since **user.options** is an array you should loop it again. By doing that you will get an object, with that object you can access your options1 and option2 easily.

please refer  working plunker:

http://embed.plnkr.co/5c3i5fY50jLP0fFgxkUX/preview

see through the code if you have any doubt.

Hope this helps

Comment: no , this cannot be used because, the number of options in `user.options` will vary, hence i cannot call it explicitly using `options1` and `options2`

Answer (score 1):

A little aside, but just found out you can render a valid list HTML using `ng-repeat-start/end` in combination with `ng-if="false"` for the given array of arrays to flatten them:

```
<ul>
  <script ng-repeat-start="user in userTypes" ng-if="false"></script>
  <li ng-repeat="item in user.options">{{item}}</li>
  <script ng-repeat-end="" ng-if="false"></script>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access the propertie of the `option` object in the second ng-repeat. Like `option.option1`

Comment: the number of options in `options` is not fixed. so this cannot be used

Comment: This solution doesn't depends on the length of the options collection. I guess your structure should be reworked.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make your `user.options` an object and not an array containing a single object.

Note the difference between these:

```
[{"option1":"11QWERT","option2":"22QWERT"}]
 {"option1":"11QWERT","option2":"22QWERT"}
```

You can then iterate the options with an ng-repeat like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular):

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in user.options">
    <p>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</p>
</li>
```