# how to use key value pair in ng-repeat with nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to print the fetched data in JSON using angular . The JSON is

`"products": {
            "65": {
                "5": {
                    "id": 5,
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "client_id": 96,
                    "ticket_id": 65,
                    "sold_by": 6,
                    "product_price": 13000,
                    "sold_from_date": 1434459600,
                    "sold_to_date": 1444741200
                },`
How to ng-repeat this in the front-end to display the data from this?

I tried this but its not working.

```
    <div ng-repeat="(product_id, product1) in acct_details.products">
                    <div ng-repeat="(product_id2, product2) in product1">
                        <tr ng-repeat="product in product2">
                            <td> <input class="chkbox-style" type="checkbox"></input>
                                 <p class="para-inline">{{product.product_name}}</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{product.product_price | currency:"&#8377;"}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{product.sold_from_date *1000| date: 'mediumDate'}}
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                                {{product.sold_to_date *1000| date:'mediumDate'}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                    </div>****
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I iterate over the keys, value in ng-repeat in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Comment: but how to do that for further nested. i am confused with the flow.

Comment: Have you tried something in your template ?

Comment: I have edited my question . Take a look and help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your JSON should be improved. JSON by itself should suffice to understand what is being represented, which in this case does not. My version of your JSON:

```
"products": {
    "product": {
        "ticket_id": 65,
        "id": 5,
        "details": {
                "product_id": 1,
                "client_id": 96,
                "sold_by": 6,
                "product_price": 13000,
                "sold_from_date": 1434459600,
                "sold_to_date": 1444741200
        }
    }
}
```

I am assuming that `65` is relevant to the `ticket_id` and that the `5` corresponds to the `id`.
Thus, I am able to use a proper JSON representation of the data in my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    {{product.ticket_id}}-{{product.id}}
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in product.details">
        {{key}}:{{value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Keeping your JSON neatly structured will always make your coding easier.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it product1 is:

```
           {
            "5": {
                "id": 5,
                "product_id": 1,
                "client_id": 96,
                "ticket_id": 65,
                "sold_by": 6,
                "product_price": 13000,
                "sold_from_date": 1434459600,
                "sold_to_date": 1444741200
            }
```

And then product2 is :

```
{
                "id": 5,
                "product_id": 1,
                "client_id": 96,
                "ticket_id": 65,
                "sold_by": 6,
                "product_price": 13000,
                "sold_from_date": 1434459600,
                "sold_to_date": 1444741200
            }
```

So you don't need the third ng-repeat. Just call product2.product_price or whatever it is you need.