# ng-repeat (iterate) over complex json object in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

One controller returns me a very complex json object:

```
{
"184": {
    "title": "THE STONE ROSES",
    "sessions": {
        "1443564000000": {
            "num": 5
        },
        "1442959200000": {
            "num": 1
        },
        "1447196400000": {
            "num": 1
        },
        "1444428000000": {
            "num": 2
        },
        "1446332400000": {
            "num": 3
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have tried to iterate over it on my view like this

```
<div class="large-6 columns" ng-repeat="item in showItems" st-raw>
    <h1>{{item.sessions}}</h1>
 </div>
```

with this code I get part if the object printed on the html response:

```
{"1443564000000":{"num":1}}
```

But as you can see, sessions has a very complex attribute (I use the id of the session to store the number of it)

I have seen that some people used to do that with ng-repeat-start, on my case using it gives me severals errors..

Comment: showItems is an object not an array, why do you want to iterate on that?

Comment: Because I need to show on my view this kind of result:
1443564000000 - 1
1444428000000 -3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to iterate over the `sessions` property, which is not an array but an object, you would have to iterate over the object's properties:

`<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">`

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/7AQF6k7hf2aZbWFmhVoX?p=preview

relevant SO questions where the example is from: [How can I iterate over the keys, value in ng-repeat in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Comment: Yeps! this is almost working...except for that I'm getting the whole session object if I iterate like this...is there a way to stringfy this object?
`<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in cartItems">
    <h1>{{key}} {{value.sessions}}</h1>
   </div> `

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Are you trying to iterate over cartItem _and_ session? If you could post a code example (jsbin) it would be helpful!

Comment: I will try to explain, I will reproduce the code on fiddle but without the real data just to see what I'm doing.

What I'm try to do is a kind of shop cart: everytime you click on date session of an item you have to add to the cart the session time and the number of times you select this date session.

What I have done is create an especific object for the event and then I push diferents attributes on it for store the sessions:

http://jsfiddle.net/dph4fg66/16/

Comment: you can easily mock data in angular using $q or just forgoing the async call. I've created a template for a simple mocking; try to recreate your issue here: http://jsbin.com/zuzoxeciba/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Another approach will be pushing elements to an array:
http://jsfiddle.net/dph4fg66/17/

But the counter initialize everytime I click