# ng-repeat showing json object Angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, list

I have a list of items that I take from a json file via one service.
At the end of the list a button can let you add every item to a list containing the elements that you have clicked/add. 
You can add same item only when you don't exceed the number of availability of items.

I have made a code that basically creates an object everytime you add an item, the problem is that the object build is not very easy for iterate ([I have made another question regarding this problem..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944618/ng-repeat-iterate-over-complex-json-object-in-angular)).
When I rendered on the view it appears like a kind of object stringify

Here is part of the code:

the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="session in sessiones">
   Date:  {{session.date | dateformated }} &nbsp
  Availability: {{session.availability}} &nbsp
  <a ng-click="addItem($index, event, session);" ng-show="addMore"> [Add to cart] </a>
```

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in cartItems">
    <h1> {{value.sessions}})</h1>
   </div>
```

the function in the controller:

```
$scope.addItem = function(index, event, session) {
  if (session.availability>0){
       $scope.cartItems = $scope.cartItems || {};
       $scope.cartItems[event.id] = $scope.cartItems[event.id] || {title:event.title, sessions:{}}
       $scope.cartItems[event.id].sessions[session.date] =          $scope.cartItems[event.id].sessions[session.date] || {num:0}
       $scope.cartItems[event.id].sessions[session.date].num++;
        session.availability-=1;
        console.log($scope.cartItems);
    }
}
```

[Here's my try on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dph4fg66/42/)

Important update---> Here is an example that ilustrates very well what I want to do: just the same but instead of repeating elements when an element is already on the list I have to count the number of times that it has been added

[Simple cart list](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gaj2jOYIy1pxIPZwzWKS?p=preview)

Comment: The fiddle seems to be missing the `sessions` scope variable

Comment: I don't know how to attached json's on fiddle...sorry!

Comment: @FrnndSgz just add the JSON string as a variable to the .js file.

Comment: @doldt I've tried...still getting nothing
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/dph4fg66/31/)

Comment: @FrnndSgz change the script include method from onload to noWrap, then the basic binding will work. Also, you're trying to reference $scope outside of a controller, which throws an additional error.

Comment: @doldt I'll try: http://jsfiddle.net/dph4fg66/38/

 Btw this example does exactly what I'm looking for except that I don't want to repeat elements, I want to count them.
[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gaj2jOYIy1pxIPZwzWKS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dph4fg66/41/)

- I didn't see the ADD+ link, so I played with that until it appeared.
- I suspected trouble with index, but it was fine.
- I noticed the $scope was a different color in the javascript, then noticed that you were assigning addItem to something that wasn't your controller.

So in the end I just moved this down to the bottom, enclosing addItem:

```
});
```

Comment: I have updated the fiddle, now with your help I can finally reproduce entirely my problem...I'm gonna edit the original question with the link.