# How to show json response values in Angular JS using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to show the values of a specific JSON in the right Order. My JSON looks like :

```
{
"A":[{"id":"21","name":"Andrea"},{"id":"22","name":"Apple"}],
"B":[{"id":"21","name":"Baby"},{"id":"22","name":"Bali"}],
"C":[{"id":"21","name":"Candle"},{"id":"22","name":"Canada"}],
}
```

How to show values with ng-repeat :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

</div>
```

like :

A

Andrea

Apple

B

Baby

Bali

C

Candle

Canada

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over the keys and values with ng-repeat in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-to-iterate-over-the-keys-and-values-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/lqoQvmXnimWYzqVU0wkg?p=preview

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, values) in items">
  {{key}}
  <div ng-repeat="item in values">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over the object with:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in jsonData">
   {{key}}
   <div ng-repeat="item in value">
      <div>{{item.name}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

edit: I see the other guys added jsfiddle so enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

If your data be like this :

```
$scope.items={
"A":[{"id":"21","name":"Andrea"},{"id":"22","name":"Apple"}],
"B":[{"id":"21","name":"Baby"},{"id":"22","name":"Bali"}],
"C":[{"id":"21","name":"Candle"},{"id":"22","name":"Canada"}],
}
```

Consider item as map and iterate for (key,value) in map and the value will be associated List. And again iterate for the list in values as -

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in items">
     {{key}}
     <div ng-repeat="item in value">
       {{item.name}}
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b51rKeXNmNr6LwHFPf9V?p=preview).

You print `key` of your json too so you should use '(key,value)' in ng-repeat to get value of key too.

code:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">
   {{key}}
    <div ng-repeat="item in value">
      {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```