# angularJS table array

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angularJS to create an table. But it didn't works so great atm.. here my problem.

Code:

```
appGenerator.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.names = [
        {"Name": "EMAIL", "StringValue": "dsa@dsada", "Type": "C"},
        {"Name": "DESC", "StringValue": "Test","Type": "C"}
        ];
});
```

HTML:

```
 <table class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="tableItem in names">
                <td ng-repeat="item in tableItem">{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

At the moment I get the whole Item. But I want the the "StringValue". 
I tested 
`<td ng-repeat="item in tableItem">{{item.StringValue}}</td>`
But it doesn't works. I don't get any output. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like the following;

```
<table class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="tableItem in names">
    <td>{{ tableItem.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ tableItem.StringValue }}</td>
    <td>{{ tableItem.Type }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You already iterated the names. Then you should use the object.

Comment: Oh god! Thanks :D so easy ^^

Comment: You can even iterate on object `{"key": "value"}` pair, please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434003/angularjs-table-array/#answer-33434098

Answer (score 2):

Your second `ng-repeat` is on object's `{"key": "value"}` pair so `ng-repeat` should be as follows:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="tableItem in names">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in tableItem">{{key}}&nbsp;{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please refer: [How can I iterate over the keys, value in ng-repeat in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Comment: You can iterate keys and values of the object like that. But what did you with this attribute 'ng-repeat="item in tableItem"'? There is no tableItem data in ngRepeat. So why did you iterate it? You should fix this code.

Comment: <td >{{ value.Name}} </td>  with this <td> tag it works. Thanks :)