# How to get current object name to display inside a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object(parent) with multiple objects(current) inside it. I use ng-repeat to display all the (current)objects. These current object has a unique name.

What I want to do is get the unique name and display it to inside the view.

This is what's inside the object(parent) when I use console.log

```
5b6055ad59040d3624c81c114d04aa2a: Object
    addons: Array[5]
    data: Object
8c56c8cbe6d415ba4d036d8dc859683: Object
    addons: Array[5]
    data: Object
c8f22c12b7aaf10fe360f438e0931a4d: Object
    addons: Array[5]
    data: Object
```

This is the view of the angular code. So I want for example "5b6055ad59040d3624c81c114d04aa2a" to show inside the h3 tags.

```
<div class="product" ng-repeat="item in cart.items">
    <ul>
        <li><h3>{{item.uniquename}}</h3></li>
        <li>
            <span class="left">Name:</span>
            <span class="right">{{item.addons[0].value}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular

Comment: @hex13 thanks man got it working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `uniquename` you refer to the key of each of the items in your array, you can iterate as key/value as follows:

```
<div class="product" ng-repeat="(uniquename, item) in cart.items">
    <ul>
        <li><h3>{{uniquename}}</h3></li>
        <li>
            <span class="left">Name:</span>
            <span class="right">{{item.addons[0].value}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. glad to help.