# display value dynamically into div

Tags: angularjs

I have an JSON like following.

```
{
"PT": {
    "value": "Week 9 Cleaning and Rotation"
},
"PREV_STATUS": {
    "value": "ordered"
}
```

Where `PT` and `PREV_STATUS` etc are ID of fields and values is its values.
list of fields and values may changes dyanamically.

i want to show in html so field `PT` can show value from JSON string.

my HTML is

```
<div style="font-size: 14px;">{{Object.editedValue.PT.value}}</div>
```

this line shows a value of PT array i.e. `Week 9 Cleaning and Rotation`

Is there any way to make field name dyanamic?

somthing like

```
 <div style="font-size: 14px;">{{Object.editedValue.{{field_NAME}}.value}}</div>
```

Because field name is dynamically generated.

Comment: Use the controller to set the value to a scope variable!

Comment: you can iterate through the Keys available using `ng-repeat`, I think you are looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Just like in JavaScript:

```
{{ Object.editedValue[field_NAME].value }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the Keys available using `ng-repeat`, I think you are looking for something like this [How can I iterate over the keys, value in ng-repeat in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular).

You can basically do something like,

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in Object.editedValue">
<div style="font-size: 14px;">{{val.value}}</div>
...
</div>
```