# orderBy not working properly with key,value pair

Tags: angularjs

I am pulling a JSON of US states with their key codes, wherein the `key` is their state code, like `NY`, and `value` is the name of the state, like `New York`. In the `<select>` dropdown, I am having trouble ordering it alphabetically by `value` even after doing `orderBy: value` (I also tried with `'value'`). It is always getting ordered by `key` for some reason.

Because of this, bugs like option `North Carolina` appearing before `Nebraska`, is happening.

*Reproducing the problem here:*

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope){

  var data = {
    "dropdowns": {
      "RI": "Rhode Island",
      "HI": "Hawaii",
      "NY": "New York",
      "GA": "Georgia",
      "NV": "Nevada",
      "TN": "Tennessee",
      "CA": "California",
      "OK": "Oklahoma",
      "ME": "Maine",
      "VA": "Virginia",
      "MI": "Michigan",
      "OH": "Ohio",
      "DE": "Delaware",
      "ID": "Idaho",
      "FL": "Florida",
      "IA": "Iowa",
      "MD": "Maryland",
      "MA": "Massachusetts",
      "SC": "South Carolina",
      "AR": "Arkansas",
      "UT": "Utah",
      "IL": "Illinois",
      "IN": "Indiana",
      "CT": "Connecticut",
      "DC": "District of Columbia",
      "MN": "Minnesota",
      "KY": "Kentucky",
      "WI": "Wisconsin",
      "AZ": "Arizona",
      "MO": "Missouri",
      "KS": "Kansas",
      "OR": "Oregon",
      "MS": "Mississippi",
      "LA": "Louisiana",
      "NH": "New Hampshire",
      "WA": "Washington",
      "NJ": "New Jersey",
      "NM": "New Mexico",
      "AK": "Alaska",
      "TX": "Texas",
      "AL": "Alabama",
      "CO": "Colorado",
      "PA": "Pennsylvania",
      "NC": "North Carolina",
      "NE": "Nebraska"
    }
  };

  $scope.retailStates = data.dropdowns;

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <select>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in retailStates | orderBy: value" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I fix this?

Please feel free to suggest me an alternate solution if you know of using `ng-options`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular team has said that it doesn't recommend using ng-repeat over the keys of an object, and [even regrets adding that functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular).  The simplest solution is probably just to transform the object into an array.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope){

  var data = {
    "dropdowns": {
      "RI": "Rhode Island",
      "HI": "Hawaii",
      "NY": "New York",
      "GA": "Georgia",
      "NV": "Nevada",
      "TN": "Tennessee",
      "CA": "California",
      "OK": "Oklahoma",
      "ME": "Maine",
      "VA": "Virginia",
      "MI": "Michigan",
      "OH": "Ohio",
      "DE": "Delaware",
      "ID": "Idaho",
      "FL": "Florida",
      "IA": "Iowa",
      "MD": "Maryland",
      "MA": "Massachusetts",
      "SC": "South Carolina",
      "AR": "Arkansas",
      "UT": "Utah",
      "IL": "Illinois",
      "IN": "Indiana",
      "CT": "Connecticut",
      "DC": "District of Columbia",
      "MN": "Minnesota",
      "KY": "Kentucky",
      "WI": "Wisconsin",
      "AZ": "Arizona",
      "MO": "Missouri",
      "KS": "Kansas",
      "OR": "Oregon",
      "MS": "Mississippi",
      "LA": "Louisiana",
      "NH": "New Hampshire",
      "WA": "Washington",
      "NJ": "New Jersey",
      "NM": "New Mexico",
      "AK": "Alaska",
      "TX": "Texas",
      "AL": "Alabama",
      "CO": "Colorado",
      "PA": "Pennsylvania",
      "NC": "North Carolina",
      "NE": "Nebraska"
    }
  };

  $scope.retailStates = [];
  for(var key in data.dropdowns){
     $scope.retailStates.push({"key": key, "value": data.dropdowns[key] }); 
  }
  

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <select>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="state in retailStates | orderBy: 'value'" value="{{state.key}}">{{state.value}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters passed to orderBy need to match a name of a property in an **array of objects** this means your data will need to be changed to look like this

```
$scope.retailStates = [ { stateCode:"RI", stateName:"Rhode Island"},
                        { stateCode:"HI", stateName:"Hawaii"}
                      ];
```

and so on.

This changes your ng-repeat to

```
ng-repeat="retailStates in retailStates | orderBy: stateName"
```