# ng repeat array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to repeat a child array of a multidimensional array with ng repeat in Angular.
My json object is this:

```
 $scope.items =   [{    "id":1,
        "BasisA":"1",
        "Basis":true,
        "personSex":"m",
        "isCollapsed":false,
        "name":"Mark Polos",
        "age":"1955",
        "results":[{"1000":{"company_name":"***","model":"***","modelname":"***","pr":222,"rating":4.5,"priority":9,"matching":1},
                    "1001":{"company_name":"***","model":"***","modelname":"***","pr":228.7,"rating":5.7,"priority":7,"matching":2},
                    "1002":{"company_name":"***","model":"***","modelname":"***","pr":241.7,"rating":1.9,"priority":4,"matching":3}
                }]
    }]
```

Itried somthing like this:

```
... data-ng-repeat="item in items">
```

And then in the table of this child:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="i in item | orderBy:'insItem.pr'">
```

Comment: Probably it should be
```<tr data-ng-repeat="i in item.results | orderBy:'insItem.pr'">```

Comment: @ema post it as answer, you answered his query.

Comment: that was a typo, sorry... however if i now do this in my ng-repeat {{i.model}} it stays empty... when i do this {{i}} t gives me all the rows though?

Comment: you should do this - <tr data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in item.results"> and then try {{val.model}}

Comment: when you test your code, then please remove the extra white-space in your json. For me the json was invalid at first. After I deleted some white space it was ok. http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like that results property is actually an "array."  If that's just a typo in your example, then disregard.  If not ... read on.

It looks like an array with a single item, and that Item is a set of properties which are, in turn, objects. In other words, you would reference the property "pr" for the result named "1000" by with code that looks like `item.results[0]["1000"].pr` NOT with code that looks the way your ng-repeat is expecting(`item.results[0].pr`).

Can you transform your items when you get them so that results is a true array?

OR - can you use a function inside of your controller that returns the array you are looking for?

**View Code:**

```
<... data-ng-repeat="result in resultsFromItem(item)" >
```

**Controller Code:**

```
$scope.resultsFromItem = function (item) {

   if(item==undefined || item.results==undefined || item.results.length==0) {
      return [];
   }

   var myResults = [];
   for (var key in item.results[0]) {
      if(item.results[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         myResults.push(item.results[0][key]);
      }
   }

   return myResults;

}
```

You might even decide to hang that "transformed" results object off each item object (so you only have to go through the transform one time) if you wanted to.

Comment: thanks can you tell me how i can convert the whole object into an array?

Comment: Wait ... which object are we talking about?  "items" or "item" or "result"?

Comment: It concerns the whole result... If i could convert the code to a proper array before usage that would make things more easier not? Then i dont have to always call that function to convert!

Comment: Got it now ... Will edit shortly to provide that option.

Answer (score 1):

You should access to the results field:

```
... data-ng-repeat="item in items">

<tr data-ng-repeat="i in item.results">
```

Since the nested array is in the results property of the main object.

Answer (score 0):

I used three nested `ng-repeat` directives to get this rolling :-) The third `ng-repeat` uses `ng-repeat="(key, value) in result"` functionality to display all result object keys and values, which I got working with the help of this answer on [how to iterate over keys and values in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15127934/2048391). The `orderBy:` part isn't yet working (if someone knows how to implement that then any help is welcomed).

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
         id: {{item.id}}, name: {{item.name}}, age: {{item.age}}, results: 
         <table>
           <tr ng-repeat="result in item.results">
             <td>
               <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
                  <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in result | orderBy: value.pr">
                    <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z8qK0e1h1OMQAClSTF5v?p=preview)