# Angular js binding dictionary to ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, dictionary

Hi all I am returning a dictionary with a key and list of objects from my controller, I would like to bind this to the table or some other using `ng-repeat`, this is how it looks when returning data from controller

[image]

This is my trail

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in dic">
<td>{{value}}</td>
```

Which is displaying entire value

Comment: Can you show code which is tried by you

Comment: I haven't tried as I am not getting the key value to bind the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how finally I got it

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in dic">
     {{key}}
 </div>
<div ng-repeat="v in value">
         {{v.requiredcolumn}}
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat provides a mechanism for accessing the key and value of an object within the iterator. For an example of this, see the answer to this post: [How can I iterate over the keys, value in ng-repeat in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Comment: No luck not able to bind the data `<div class="panel panel-default"
                             ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"> {{key}}`</div>`