# Loop within a loop in Angular

Tags: angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json that looks like this:

```
var json = {
brands: [{
    name: "sony",
    count: "3"
}, {
    name: "canon",
    count: "5"
}],
countries: [{
    name: "France",
    count: "1"
}, {
    name: "Spain",
    count: "7"
}]
};
```

I'm trying to display this as facets with Angular
**Brands**
 sony(3)
 canon(5)

**Countries**
 France(1)
 Spain(7)

I could easily hardcode Brands and Countries and do something like

```
<div>
  Brands
  <p ng-repeat="brand in json.brands>{{brand.name}}({{brand.count}})</p>
</div>
<div>
  Countries
  <p ng-repeat="country in json.countries>{{country.name}}({{country.count}})</p>
</div>
```

BUT I'd rather do this without hard-coding and read "Brands" and "Countries" dynamically, basically having a loop in a loop.
Is that even feasible?

tnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate throught key & values of an angular object:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in json">
  {{key}} 
  <p ng-repeat="brand in value>
      {{brand.name}}({{brand.count}})
  </p>
</div>
```

[How can I iterate over the keys, value in ng-repeat in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Comment: @kozureookami No worries ! Don't forget to mark the answer as valid to close the question !