# cant see data on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase to get some data and display it,
My issue that i cant see my list on the template.
My factory is

```
 return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
```

and my object on firebase is

```
{
  "contacts" : [ {
    "active" : true,
    "lastName" : "fdg",
    "name" : "sdfdsf",
    "number" : "052045454",
    "table" : 3
  }]}
```

and the controller is

```
 $scope.contacts =Items;
```

and display it just :

```
ng-repeat="(key, contact) in contacts
```

what can be the issue? i can see that firebase it return data...

Comment: Items is a factory that return firebase object ....controller("ListCtrl", function($scope, Items) {
  $scope.items = Items;

Comment: Could you provide a plunker, or at least more code? Looking at this makes many things appear possibly incorrect. For instance, it looks like the template is incorrect, and possibly has a solution in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular

Comment: `Console.log($scope.items)` to check whether factory returns the correct data.

Comment: [{"active":true,"lastName":"fdg","name":"rimsdcan","number":"052045453","table":3}]

Comment: If `{
  "contacts" : [ {
    "active" : true,
    "lastName" : "fdg",
    "name" : "sdfdsf",
    "number" : "052045454",
    "table" : 3
  }]}` is your `Items`, then you should use `$scope.contacts = Items.contacts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, there are multiple things that look wrong in the question. But I suspect most likely issue is that contacts is an array, not map. So, what you need to do most likely is something along these lines:

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index">
Active: {{contact.active}}, Contact Name: {{contact.name}} ...
</div>
```

Or these (note the indexed access):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in contacts[0]">
key: {{key}}, Value: {{value}} ...
</div>
```

P.S. "track by $index" part may or may not be required depending on your data.