# Filter ng-repeat with key from parent ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(key, value) in categories">
    <h5>{{ value }}</h5>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in $parent.posts | filter: key">{{ post.name }} -- {{ post.category }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want the nested `ng-repeat` of the post be to filtered by the category `key`.

The idea is to have each post displaying related posts, where `{{ post.category }}` is same as `{{ value }}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate over the keys, value in ng-repeat in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Comment: @DurgpalSingh No, not duplicate. My question is, how to use the `key` in the first ng-repeat as filter for the second ng-repeat. The link you gave is how to do `(key, value) in dataset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That requirement to iterate over `object` and to filter the child `ng-repeat` using the `key of parent` can be achieved by using a `custom function` which in turn returns the object. Check the sample application created below.

```js
var app = angular.module('sample', []);

app.controller('samplecontroller', function($scope) {

  $scope.filterKey = function(value) {
    return {
      name: value
    };
  };

  $scope.categories = {
    'John': 'English'
  };
  $scope.posts = [{
    name: 'John',
    category: 'General'
  }, {
    name: 'James',
    category: 'Restricted'
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="samplecontroller">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="(key, value) in categories">
      <h5>{{ value }}</h5>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in $parent.posts | filter: filterKey(key)">{{ post.name }} -- {{ post.category }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: For my use case (in relation with `$firebaseArray`) I ended up doing `return value;` instead of `return { name: value }` Thank you