# Need help looping through json key value pairs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am using AngularJS and I've successfully pulled in exchange rates from fixer.io but I'm having trouble looping through the key value pairs to get **country** and **rate** data. Right now all I'm able to get is rate and I need the country as well. Can someone tell me what I'm missing in my code? I've included what the rates look like on the fixer.io website further down in this post.

**HTML5**

```
<div ng-controller="AngularJSCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="x in data.rates">
        <li>{{ x }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.service('dataService', function($http) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    this.getData = function(callbackFunc) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.fixer.io/latest',
            params: 'limit=10, sort_by=created:desc',
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Token token=xxxxYYYYZzzz'}
        }).success(function(data){
            // With the data succesfully returned, call our callback
            callbackFunc(data);
        }).error(function(){
            alert("error");
        });
     }
});

myApp.controller('AngularJSCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.data = null;
    dataService.getData(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.data = dataResponse;
    });
});
```

**rates as they appear on the website**

```
{
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2016-09-20",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 1.4812,
        "BGN": 1.9558,
        "BRL": 3.6473,
        "CAD": 1.4792,
        "CHF": 1.0943,
        "CNY": 7.4604,
        "CZK": 27.022,
        "DKK": 7.452,
        "GBP": 0.86213,
        "HKD": 8.6753,
        "HRK": 7.5127,
        "HUF": 309.12,
        "IDR": 14698.01,
        "ILS": 4.2231,
        "INR": 74.962,
        "JPY": 113.93,
        "KRW": 1252.4,
        "MXN": 21.965,
        "MYR": 4.631,
        "NOK": 9.2648,
        "NZD": 1.522,
        "PHP": 53.527,
        "PLN": 4.2975,
        "RON": 4.4513,
        "RUB": 72.5141,
        "SEK": 9.5763,
        "SGD": 1.5237,
        "THB": 38.909,
        "TRY": 3.3275,
        "USD": 1.1184,
        "ZAR": 15.5144
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate over the keys, value in ng-repeat in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as other answers with live example.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.data = 
{
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2016-09-20",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 1.4812,
        "BGN": 1.9558,
        "BRL": 3.6473,
        "CAD": 1.4792,
        "CHF": 1.0943,
        "CNY": 7.4604,
        "CZK": 27.022,
        "DKK": 7.452,
        "GBP": 0.86213,
        "HKD": 8.6753,
        "HRK": 7.5127,
        "HUF": 309.12,
        "IDR": 14698.01,
        "ILS": 4.2231,
        "INR": 74.962,
        "JPY": 113.93,
        "KRW": 1252.4,
        "MXN": 21.965,
        "MYR": 4.631,
        "NOK": 9.2648,
        "NZD": 1.522,
        "PHP": 53.527,
        "PLN": 4.2975,
        "RON": 4.4513,
        "RUB": 72.5141,
        "SEK": 9.5763,
        "SGD": 1.5237,
        "THB": 38.909,
        "TRY": 3.3275,
        "USD": 1.1184,
        "ZAR": 15.5144
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
  <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data.rates">
    {{key}} - {{value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over object properties. Check [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
   <div ng-controller="AngularJSCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="(country, rate) in data.rates">
            <li>{{ country }} - {{ rate }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` lets you [iterate over both the key and the value of an object's properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties).  Since that object is a dictionary with the proper key and value pairs, just update your `ng-repeat` definition:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.rates">
    <li>{{key}}: {{ value }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the others answers' use of ng-repeat is correct, I think, structurally, you should do it differently. It doesn't make sense to make a new `<ul>` with a single `<li>` for each key/value pair. You should probably have a single `<ul>` and have a child `<li>` for each country/rate like so:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(country, rate) in data.rates" ng-bind="country + ': ' + rate"></li>
</ul>
```

Also, interpolation ( aka {{ }} ) should be avoided whenever possible. It is slow, and renders the ugly braces on slower connections when loading the page. Use `ng-bind` instead.

If you wanted to get somewhat fancier formatting, you can do something like this:

```js
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
  myModule.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      "base": "EUR",
      "date": "2016-09-20",
      "rates": {
        "AUD": 1.4812,
        "BGN": 1.9558,
        "BRL": 3.6473,
        "CAD": 1.4792,
        "CHF": 1.0943,
        "CNY": 7.4604,
        "CZK": 27.022,
        "DKK": 7.452,
        "GBP": 0.86213,
        "HKD": 8.6753,
        "HRK": 7.5127,
        "HUF": 309.12,
        "IDR": 14698.01,
        "ILS": 4.2231,
        "INR": 74.962,
        "JPY": 113.93,
        "KRW": 1252.4,
        "MXN": 21.965,
        "MYR": 4.631,
        "NOK": 9.2648,
        "NZD": 1.522,
        "PHP": 53.527,
        "PLN": 4.2975,
        "RON": 4.4513,
        "RUB": 72.5141,
        "SEK": 9.5763,
        "SGD": 1.5237,
        "THB": 38.909,
        "TRY": 3.3275,
        "USD": 1.1184,
        "ZAR": 15.5144
      }
    }
  }]);
```

```css
ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #cecece;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul style="width: 150px;">
    <li ng-repeat="(country, rate) in data.rates">
      <span ng-bind="country + ': '"></span><span style="float: right;" ng-bind="rate | number:4"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```