# use of operators( >,<,==,!=) in ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-ng-class

I want to use Operators to check if value is greater or equal to other number or variable in ng-class, and then apply a style class accordingly. Basically i want to color the div based on their prob.

Is the usage of ng-class correct?
It prints the value of

```
{{1-apStats.preMappedProbability.toFixed(3)}}
```

but the ng-class tag doesn't work. Any reasons?

```
 <div ng-class="(1-apStats.preMappedProbability.toFixed(3) >=0.5) ? 'yellowClass':'redClass'"> {{1-apStats.preMappedProbability.toFixed(3)}} </div>
```

What am I doing wrong.? Thank you

Comment: That's not the correct syntax to iterate over the key/value pairs of an object. Use an array, or use the right syntax: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Also in your template you are using `1-prob.p` instead of `prob1.p` and look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular) to see how to iterate properly over an object also it's often recommended to convert the data to an array as you will see from the comments in the accepted answer.

Comment: there are a list of probability objects, like prob1, prob2, ;prob 3 and so on. And I'm iterating over those objects. Anyways , i'll check if it;s incorrect. Just tell me if the ng-class is used properly or not?

Comment: First convert your object with a loop thanks to Object.keys(probability) And make your ng-repeat on this table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Subhash

In ng-class directive, first you need to give class name then condition like following -

```
ng-class="{moreBtnGray : condition}"
```

In your case - you should use two ng-class and maintain condition accordingly.

```
 <div ng-class="{yellowClass: condition1, redClass:condition2}">{{1-prob.p}} </div>
```

Comment: can You take a look at the edited question and tell me ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

```
<element ng-class="class : conditionExpression"></element>
```

Modified your `ng-class` this way

```
<div ng-class="'yellowClass': 1-apStats.preMappedProbability.toFixed(3) >= 0.5; 'redClass' : anotherCondition">{{1-apStats.preMappedProbability.toFixed(3)}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in probability">
 <div ng-class="(1-item.prob.p)>=0.5 ? 'yellowClass':'redClass'">{{1-item.prob.p}} </div>
```