# Angular Show ng-repeat Key

Tags: json, angular, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to display the key in the products AL200W401 (without xxxx) using ng-repeat.  in my HTML code its displaying the AL200W401xxxx.  How to go about this thanks.

JSON

```
{  
    "kits":"B11D0W201,AL200W401",
     "dateTo":"13/12/2016",
     "orders":[  
         {  
             "AL200W401":1,
             "B11D0W201":0,
             "date":"13 Dec 16"
         }
     ],
    "dateFrom":"12/12/2016",
    "products":[  
    {  
        "AL200W401":"AL200W401xxxx",
        "B11D0W201":"B11D0W201xxxx"
    }
    ]
}
```

HTML

```
<th ng-repeat="column in products">{{column}}</th>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is other similar questions where solution is sited. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular) for example

So you can do it this way:

```
<th ng-repeat="(key,value) in products[0]">{{key}}</th>
```

Please check this working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hd84335/j0dr7bbp/

Answer (score 1):

```
<th ng-repeat="(key,value) in products[0]">{{key}}</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope) {
    $scope.jsonObj = {  
    "kits":"B11D0W201,AL200W401",
     "dateTo":"13/12/2016",
     "orders":[  
         {  
             "AL200W401":1,
             "B11D0W201":0,
             "date":"13 Dec 16"
         }
     ],
    "dateFrom":"12/12/2016",
    "products":[  
    {  
        "AL200W401":"AL200W401xxxx",
        "B11D0W201":"B11D0W201xxxx"
    }
    ]
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in jsonObj.products[0]">{{key}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit,  this is surely working as well and thanks for the example.  I can only upvote one answer though.

Comment: @June No problem !! :)