# How can I iterate over a dataset while only extracting properties specified in an array?

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on a project in Angular. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular), but it's not quite what I need.

I make an API call and get a JSON object back that has twenty plus properties. So a user might have the following properties and then some:

```
user.Name
user.Nickname
user.DOB
user.FavoriteColor
user.Address
...
```

I also have an array that looks like this.

```
$scope.ThePropertiesIWantToShow = [
                { propertyID: 1, displayValue: 'Name' },
                { propertyID: 3 displayValue: 'DOB' },
                { propertyID: 5 displayValue: 'Address' },
```

I have a table where I'd like to show this data, but I only want certain properties displayed (the ones in the array above). If I wanted to manually show everything in `ThePropertiesIWantToShow`, I might do something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.DOB}{</td>
    <td>{{user.Address}{</td>
</tr>
```

However, both the JSON data and `ThePropertiesIWantToShow` array are much larger. I'd like to know how to use `ng-repeat` to do something like the following pseudocode, so that I don't have to type out each property manually. Plus, if I needed to make changes, I could just change the array, and it would be reflected in multiple places:

```
for each user in users
     for each property in ThePropertiesIWantToShow
          <td>user.property</td>
```

Per the previously linked question, I know that I can do something like this to get *all* properties:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td ng-repeat="(property, value) in user">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

but this gives me all the data from the API call, and I'd only like to display the properties provided in the array for each user.

Comment: You have oversimplified the data sample. This is a guessing game on our end without a better representation of what you are actually working with

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question to make it more complete.

Comment: Done. Let me know if there's anything else I can do to improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is something like:

```
$scope.fields =['Name','DOB','Address'];
```

Then in view you repeat the fields within each row:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td ng-repeat="field in fields">{{user[field]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I'm looking for! But is there a way to do that while still maintaining the format of `ThePropertiesIWantToShow`? For example, is there something like this: `<td ng-repeat="property in ThePropertiesIWantToShow">{{user[property.displayValue]}}</td>`?

Comment: Thanks! I figured it would be something simple; I was just struggling with the syntax.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well, you are trying to do this:

Declare this function in your Angular controller:

```
$scope.getUserProperty = function(user, property) {
    return user[property];
}
```

And then use it for getting user properties

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <div ng-repeat="p in properties">
      {{getUserProperty(user, p.displayValue)}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Working demo on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7t8evbb/)