# Using AngularJS select element to set a variable to an object instead of a string

Tags: angularjs

The following code works.  My question is whether this is the right way to do it.

The variable **devices** is an array of objects and when the user selects one the variable **selDev** gets set to one of those objects.  If I make **selDev** the model via the **ng-model** attribute then it gets a string, not the original model.

```
    <p>
        <label>Device Id:</label>
        <select ng-model="selDevIndex"
            ng-change="selDev = devices[selDevIndex]">
            <option value="">(no device)</option>
            <option ng-repeat="device in devices "
                    value="{{$index}}">
                {{device.id}}: {{device.type}} {{device.mfr}}
                {{device.serial}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </p>
```

I find this a little clumsy due to the inclusion of the $index reference.  Also this technique would not work if **devices** was an object an not an array.   Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-options`

**HTML:**

```
  <select ng-model="selectedModel" 
          ng-options="device as device.text for device in devices track by device.id">
  </select>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
$scope.selectedModel;
$scope.devices = [{
   id: 1,
   text: "Device1"
}, {
   id: 2,
   text: "Device2"
}];
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdz5sy1e/4/)

If you have to loop over an object instead of an array, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-can-i-iterate-over-the-keys-value-in-ng-repeat-in-angular)