# How do you bind to name of array in object array?

Tags: angularjs

I have an object with an array:

```
 {
    People: [
        {
            label: 'label1',
            type: 'type1'
        },
        {
            label: 'label2',
            type: 'type2'
        }],
    Places: [
       {
            label: 'label1',
            type: 'type1'
        },
        {
            label: 'label2',
            type: 'type2'
        }]
}
```

I have an ng-repeat to create a list. I can bind to the properties inside People and Places but cannot bind to the name 'People' and 'Places'.

My html is something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in vm.categories">
   <button>{{category}}</button>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="subcategory in category">
        <a href="#"> {{subcategory.label}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </button>
 </div>
```

so subcategories are all fine but {{category}} doesn't return People/Places. How do I bind to the name of the array in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by using [iterate over the keys and values with ng-repeat in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-to-iterate-over-the-keys-and-values-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

```js
angular.module("test",[]).controller("testc",function($scope) {   
      $scope.categories = {
People: [
    {
        label: 'label1',
        type: 'type1'
    },
    {
        label: 'label2',
        type: 'type2'
    }],
Places: [
   {
        label: 'label1',
        type: 'type1'
    },
    {
        label: 'label2',
        type: 'type2'
    }]
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testc">
   <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in categories">
   <button>{{key}}</button>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="subcategory in value">
    <a href="#"> {{subcategory.label}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
   </button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3214545 Could you please do mark as an answer if it works for you. :)

Comment: apologies for the delay, it wouldnt let me mark it for a few mins :)

Comment: No problem! Great & Thanks :)