# Angularjs Loop the record based on array

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular js

after hit I got response below response how to loop it

**one div name then value like this i want to loop**

**my response**

```
{  
   "my2":[  
      {  
         "id":5,
         "cuid":20,
         "name":"my2",
         "month":"04",
         "created_at":"2018-04-01 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"2018-04-11 00:00:00",
         "time":"04:32 PM",
         "status":"D"
      },
      {  
         "id":4,
         "cuid":20,
         "name":"my2",
         "month":"04",
         "created_at":"2018-04-02 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
         "time":"12:10 PM",
         "status":"P"
      },
   ],
   "my":[  
      {  
         "id":44,
         "cuid":21,
         "name":"my",
         "month":"04",
         "created_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
         "time":"09:08 PM",
         "status":"P"
      }
   ],
   "Testing":[  
      {  
         "id":43,
         "cuid":19,
         "name":"Testing",
         "month":"04",
         "created_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
         "time":"09:05 PM",
         "status":"P"
      }
   ]
}
```

i try this

```
<div ng-repeat="data in reports" class="all_report">



           <div ng-repeat="data in reports">
{{reports.indexOf(data)}}
</div>
                <!--<div class="date">
                    {{data.created_at}} <br/>
                <span class="month">{{data.created_at}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="status">{{data.status}}</div>-->
            </div>
```

but it not print anything how to print in div format

I don't know how to print

I tried above but not printing

how to achieve this to print in ng-repet?

Comment: Because it's an `Object` --> `{}`, its not an array.

Comment: I am new from angularjs i don't know how to loop it can you please help it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over the keys and values with ng-repeat in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-to-iterate-over-the-keys-and-values-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in reports"` to iterate over the keys-value pairs in your `reports` object.  For your specific case, the HTML would look something like the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in reports" class="all_report">
  <div>{{key}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="data in value">
    <div>{{$index}}</div>
    <!-- Access data from the individual report rows here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

look I can help you with your question, but it would be better if you write the answer you expect to see from `JSON`, to be able to accommodate `HTML`, but look at `angularJS` with ng-repeat helps you navigate the `JSON`, but as long as you have Well built the `JSON`, it suits you a bit the `div`, if it's really what you need.
I leave a link where you can support

https://jptacek.com/2013/10/angularjs-introducing-ng-repeat/

```
$scope.test = {
   "my2":[
      {
         "id":5,
         "cuid":20,
         "name":"my2",
         "month":"04",
         "created_at":"2018-04-01 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"2018-04-11 00:00:00",
         "time":"04:32 PM",
         "status":"D"
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "cuid":20,
         "name":"my2",
         "month":"04",
         "created_at":"2018-04-02 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
         "time":"12:10 PM",
         "status":"P"
      },
   ],
   "my":[
      {
         "id":44,
         "cuid":21,
         "name":"my",
         "month":"04",
         "created_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
         "time":"09:08 PM",
         "status":"P"
      }
   ],
   "Testing":[
      {
         "id":43,
         "cuid":19,
         "name":"Testing",
         "month":"04",
         "created_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"2018-04-12 00:00:00",
         "time":"09:05 PM",
         "status":"P"
      }
   ]
}
```

In HTML, something like that can go...

```
    <div ng-repeat="data in test" class="all_report">
            <div ng-repeat="x in data">
                    {{x}}
            </div>
     </div>
```